# One big call to model, or lots of little ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In one of my views, I need to present alot of statistics about the data in the model and the nested models. For the nested models, there are alot of sums and counts with various conditions.

Is it better to write individual methods for each statistic I need, which generates lots of SQL calls but makes nice short pieces of code? Or should I write a method that just loops over each nested model once, computes all the counts/sums manually, and returns the data in a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if breaking the big query into independent queries forces you to, for example, join twice a same pair of tables, or reading twice a same table, then it is not a good strategy.

If that's not the case, you may want to break the query into independent queries for better legibility and reusability.

Use EXPLAIN to analyze your queries, try different ones and test performance with considerable amount of test data. Consider creating indexes for big tables with many records.